# how to use "cond" in scheme?

Tags: scheme, racket

I am trying to implement a game theory algorithm by using scheme. I wrote a code piece which is named tit for two tat. Here is the code:

```
(define (tit-for-two-tat my-history other-history)
 (cond ((empty-history? my-history) 'c)
    ((= 'c (most-recent-play other-history)) 'c) 
    ((= 'c (second-most-recent-play other-history)) 'c)
    (else 'd)))
```

I also tried to write it like this:

```
(define (tit-for-two-tat my-history other-history)
 (cond ((empty-history? my-history) 'c)
    ((= 'c (or (most-recent-play other-history) (second-most-recent-play other-history))) 'c)
    (else 'd)))
```

The game case is 'prisoner's dilemma'. c means coordinate d means defect. When I try to run this code it gives the following error in both type of codes:

```
expects type <number> as 1st argument, given: 'c; other arguments were: 'c
```

I am running it by giving this function as a parameter to the function "play-loop". play-loop is given to me.

What might be the problem? Thank you for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling the `=` function on a symbol `'c` but `=` requires a number.  It looks like `eq?` would be the proper function for your equivalence check.

Answer (score 1):

You're comparing against `'c`, which is a symbol - then you must use `eq?` for equality comparison. Or for a more general equality testing procedure, use `equal?`, it'll work for most data types (strings, numbers, symbols, etc.) In particular:

```
(define (tit-for-two-tat my-history other-history)
  (cond ((empty-history? my-history) 'c)
        ((equal? 'c (most-recent-play other-history)) 'c) 
        ((equal? 'c (second-most-recent-play other-history)) 'c)
        (else 'd)))
```